# azure permission to create "service principal"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Hello how are you? Im only owner of my organization subscription in Azure and I need to create service principals.

How can I give permission to my user? Or can I create a new role to assign this permission?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note:** The roles of the subscription and the roles of Azure Active directory are different.

> Im only owner of my organization subscription in Azure and I need to
>   create service principals.

You can follow this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

> How can I give permission to my user? Or can I create a new role to assign this permission?

If I understand your issue correctly, you want to give the user permission to create service principals. If you are the admin of your Azure Active Directory, you can grant the user Application administrator role. Then the user will be able to create service principals. You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal).

Answer (score 0):

Azure Active Directory now has the [Application Developer Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#application-developer) that should be the smallest built-in role you can assign to your users/pipeline service principals for this use-case.

You could also think about creating a custom role if the scenario requires and the conditions (e.g. AAD pricing tier) allow for it.